# Query Couchbase Views from Excel using Simba ODBC Driver

Tags: excel, odbc, couchbase, couchbase-view, simba

I am trying to query Couchbase data from Microsoft Office Excel using Simba ODBC Driver.

Querying Table using below statement works:

[image]

However, when I tried to query views it doesn't work, kept saying "Cannot create table ..."

[image]

Here's one of the many statements I tried to query above View

```
SELECT *
FROM Couchbase.default.`travel-sample`.`_design/dev_test` .`test_view` `travel-sample`
```

Is my syntax wrong? Or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

For the benefits of other readers: this question was answered in the comments to [this blog post](http://blog.couchbase.com/using-the-couchbase-odbc-driver-with-microsoft-excel#comment-2198571710). *Querying views is currently not supported by the driver because N1QL doesn't have access to map-reduce views.*